# IE10 CSS div float issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

Site: http://www.rmgnetworks.com/company

The following is puzzling me...

In Chrome, Firefox & Safari the search box and upper links are fine.

[image]

IE10 shifts the search box and upper links to the left and over the start of the main navigation.

[image]

What would be the IE10 hack to sort this out?

Comment: Give `clear: both` (before `float: left`) to `#menu nav-collapse`

Comment: thanks Mr_Green ... always something really simple!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `clear: both` (before `float: left;`) to `#menu .nav-collapse`.

`#menu .nav-collapse` is present in your `template.css` file. (*just elongating my answer*)

```
#menu .nav-collapse{
     clear: both;
     float: left;
}
```